# Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install (Laravel 6)

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I've installed a Vagrant box for Laravel following this command: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead --box-version 8.1.0`  (Box successfully added)

[image]

Once I tried `vagrant up` (Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...)

```
D:\Labs\laravel6>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'laravel6' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> laravel6: Box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    laravel6: Box Provider: virtualbox
    laravel6: Box Version: >= 8.2.0
==> laravel6: Loading metadata for box 'laravel/homestead'
    laravel6: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead
==> laravel6: Adding box 'laravel/homestead' (v8.2.1) for provider: virtualbox
    laravel6: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/8.2.1/providers/virtualbox.box
    laravel6: Download redirected to host: vagrantcloud-files-production.s3.amazonaws.com
    laravel6: Progress: 0% (Rate: 249k/s, Estimated time remaining: 1:26:16)==> laravel6: Waiting for cleanup before exiting...
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you wish to use the box version 8.1.0 of Homestead. From the Vagrant documentation that can be found here:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/versioning.html#version-constraints

> You can constrain a Vagrant environment to a specific version or
>   versions of a box using the Vagrantfile by specifying the
>   config.vm.box_version option.
>
> **If this option is not specified, the latest version is always used.**

If you would like to just get it up and running I would recommend running:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
vagrant up
```

Best regards